# How can I get user input from main process when using subprocess in Python

Tags: python, subprocess

For example, program1.py call program2.py:

program1.py

```
subprocess.Popen("program2.py", stdin=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

program2.py

```
user_input = input("Yes or No?")
```

But when I run program1, the program2 cannot get the user input from the main process in my case. It says "EOF when reading a line". Could you give me some advice to get user input.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing any data to `program2.py`.  I assume you are using Python 3, from the use of `input` (instead of `raw_input` in Python 2).  Here is how I would do it:

```
import subprocess
import sys

cmd = [sys.executable, 'program2.py'] 
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.communicate('Y'.encode())
```

Passes "Y" through to the second program.  The `encode()` is required in Python 3, but not Python 2.  This is because Python 3 strings are multi-byte, whereas the `stdin` stream uses single byte strings, like Python 2 strings.  No changes are required at the `program2.py` end.

Comment: Thank you! But I want to get the user input. And also, there may be more than one user inputs.

Comment: OK, maybe I mis-understood.  Are you saying you want to pass data from program1 to program2, or from program2 to program1?  I have shown you how to get data from program1 to program2, for the other way around then program2 must transmit it in some way.